# How can I manually take multiple snapshots in firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a ticket generator using javascript. I am using firebase to give the users a code that has already been stored on the database. my database is layed out like this:

```
"qrcodes" : {
    "23KU8877" : {
          "email" : "person@email.com",
          "ticketgenerated" : "true"
    },
    "288RX9U5" : {
          "email" : "person2@email.com",
          "ticketgenerated" : "true"
    }
}
```

my script allows me to get the first code in the qrcodes list and then move it to another database where another website processes it. But I was wanting to find a way that will make a function take a new snapshot everytime it is run.

The functions that grab the data from firebase are here:

```
function generatehtml(){
    ticketname = document.getElementById('name').value;
    ticketemail = document.getElementById('email').value;
    adultnumber = document.getElementById('adults').value;
    childnumber = document.getElementById('child').value;

    while (functionruncount < inputnumber){
        grabfirebasecode();
    }    
}

function grabfirebasecode(){
    ref.limitToFirst(1).once('value', function(snapshot) {
            for(key in snapshot.val()){
                genvar = snapshot.child(key + "/ticketgenerated" ).val();
                var genvarpath = "test/" + key + "/ticketgenerated";
                if (genvar === "false"){
                    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                        ref.child(childSnapshot.key).remove();
                    });
                    ref2.child(key).set({
                        email: ticketemail,
                        ticketgenerated: "true",
                    });
                    createticket();
                } 
            }

        });
    functionruncount ++;
}
```

so if the code above runs succesully and grabs the first child of the qrcode list (e.g "23KU8877"), it will stay the same no matter how many times the function loops.

I am not sure how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Daniel Martinez

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but if you're asking why the query always reads the same item, it's because you do `ref.limitToFirst(1).` But I find it hard to understand what `grabfirebasecode` is trying to do either way. Can you describe its goal?

Comment: because I won't know what the code will be (I am trying to make it random) the function will find the first child under the "qrcodes" list and grab its value. So using my database example at the top of the page, the "genvar" variable will be equal to "23KU8877". the if statement checks if the code has been used for another ticket by looking if it's ticketgenerated  variable if equal to false. If it is equal to false, it will delete from the database where all the codes are stored and then upload all the same data to another database where I have another website sending out emails to the user.

Comment: so since I delete the child once the function runs, what I though would happen is that the next time the function runs, it would pick up the next child. so lets say "23KU8877" got deleted on the first run then on the second run the function would pick up "288RX9U5" since it has now become the first child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attaching a same listener multiple times in a tight loop. All those listeners start at pretty much the same time, and thus all see the same value from the database. To get a next code, you must be sure to only start reading the next code after you've deleted the previous one. A common way to do this is with a recursive function:

```
function generatehtml(){
    ticketname = document.getElementById('name').value;
    ticketemail = document.getElementById('email').value;
    adultnumber = document.getElementById('adults').value;
    childnumber = document.getElementById('child').value;

    grabfirebasecode(inputnumber);
}

function grabfirebasecode(inputnumber){
  if (inputnumber > 0) {
    ref.limitToFirst(1).once('value', function(snapshot) {
        for(key in snapshot.val()){
            genvar = snapshot.child(key + "/ticketgenerated" ).val();
            var genvarpath = "test/" + key + "/ticketgenerated";
            if (genvar === "false"){
                var promises = [];
                snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                    promises.push(ref.child(childSnapshot.key).remove());
                });
                promises.push(
                  ref2.child(key).set({
                    email: ticketemail,
                    ticketgenerated: "true",
                  })
                );
                Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
                  grabfirebasecode(inputnumber-1);
                });
                createticket();
            } 
        }
    });
  }
}
```

So this code builds an array of promises, one for each database operation that happen asynchronously. When all those operations completes, it calls itself again with one lover number.

If your `createticket()` also performs asynchronous operations, you might want to also include it in the `promises` array so that its work is completed before the next iteration starts.

Comment: You're welcome. I recommend reading up on asynchronous operations and promises, as these things will keep coming up when you work with modern web APIs.